# Help JS Link Problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I need please help by my JS Link problem.
I want to lock a column in a form when it has a value inside.
To do this I try this code. It works but when I click on save the value in the title filed will not be saved.

This is the code I used
  var _TitleField = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
    var _TitleFieldId = _TitleField.fieldSchema.Id;
    var _TitleFieldName = _TitleField.fieldName;
    var _TitleFieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;

```
var _TitleFieldDiv = _TitleFieldName + '_' + _TitleFieldId + '_$TextField';

var result = "";


if (_TitleFieldValue) {
result = "<div><input type='text' id='" + _TitleFieldId + "' name= '" + _TitleFieldName + "' value= '" + _TitleFieldValue +  "'disabled='disabled' /></div>";
} else {
result = "<div id='" + _TitleFieldDiv + "'><input type='text' id='" + _TitleFieldId + "' title= '" + _TitleFieldName + "' value='' maxlength='255' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'></div>";  
};
```

return result;

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Stefan, you need to register callbacks so that SharePoint will call them at appropriate times. In this case while saving the item.

```
formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () { })
```

In the above function you got to return your fieldvalue so that sharepoint will pick it while saving the item.

Please let me know if you have any questions.